# How can i list all stopped services in the order that they were stopped

Tags: linux, debian, command-line

I have a Debian server on which there are certain stopped services. I would like to know how can i list all the services in the order that they were stopped. Also would like to get the time when they were stopped.

Comment: Which version of Debian?

Comment: I'm using Debian 7.9 on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find out what processes are running on your server is to run the top command:

became root

```
 top
```

or

```
 sudo apt-get install htop
```

became root

```
  htop
```

or

```
  ps
```

to kill process

```
  kill PID_of_target_process
```

You can list all services and their status by:

```
  service --status-all
```

Save Process Snapshot to a file

```
 top -b -n1 > /tmp/process.log
```

you can email result to yourself:

```
 top -b -n1 | mail -s 'Process snapshot' yourmaildotcom
```